# How to run ktor application?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, ktor

I've created a Ktor application with Gradle and I followed the tutorial on https://ktor.io/quickstart/quickstart/gradle.html#initial.
At the end it says:

> And then go to Run -> Edit Configurations select the blog.BlogAppKt
>   configuration and change its Main class to:
>   io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain
>
> Now when we run the new configuration, the application will start
>   again.

I am searching for the option but could not find it:

[image]

The gradle file looks as follows:

```
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.61"
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"


val ktor_version = "1.3.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    compile("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version")
    compile("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktor_version")
    compile("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
    testCompile(group = "junit", name = "junit", version = "4.12")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

application {
    mainClassName = "io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain"
}
```

**Update**

I'v tried following configuration:

[image]

But as you can, there is a error message.

What do I have to add to run the Ktor app?

Comment: Do you have the Kotlin and Gradle plugins installed?

Comment: Yes. Both are installed.

Comment: Which JDK version are you using? I can reproduce your issue with OpenJDK 13, but not with OpenJDK 8. I think you should follow this issue: https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/321

Answer (score 4):

You can manually run Main function, after that it will become available

Answer (score 2):

If it's not there, create a new one with the plus button.

You can select kotlin and then fill out the main class, etc.

Comment: It says `10:22 Error running 'Run': Class 'io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain' not found in module 'webservice'`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new Run configuration from template Application, not from Kotlin template. (And then fill `Main class` and `Use classpath of module` fields)

source:
https://ktor.io/servers/engine.html#running-the-application-from-inside-the-ide

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier if you install the Ktor plugin on intellij. That's the first thing I do usually when starting a Ktor project.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have encountered [a known bug](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/321). See the comments [starting here](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/321#issuecomment-420718806).

When you use JDK 9 or later, you would see this stack trace if you run that configuration:

```
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules ktor.http.jvm and ktor.server.core export package io.ktor.http to module ktor.http.cio.jvm
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolveFail(Resolver.java:885)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.failTwoSuppliers(Resolver.java:797)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.checkExportSuppliers(Resolver.java:718)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.finish(Resolver.java:362)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:141)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolveAndBind(Configuration.java:316)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor$1.resolveAndBind(ModuleDescriptor.java:2693)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModuleBootstrap.boot(ModuleBootstrap.java:361)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.initializeClassLoaders(ClassLoader.java:210)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.initialize(Thread.java:428)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:153)
```

If you switch to JDK 8, then you might see an error in the run configuration dialog, but the application will run.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle build is failing. Choose different JVM(download if required) in ide settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Build Tools>Gradle::Gradle JVM. (Try JDK-14 or 15)